# Firefox : canvas.toDataURL in image.onload but returning transparent image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I know that the image must be complete, its loading finished before using the toDataURL function on the canvas, put the code in the image.onload function ensures that.

Also have tried {preserveDrawingBuffer : true} in canvas.getContext.

This is not working in Firefox but works in Chrome...

My code :

```
var imageWidth = imageHeight = 45;
var image = new Image();

console.log(image);

image.onload = (function (imageWidth, imageHeight) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    d3.select(canvas)
    .attr('width', imageWidth + "px")
    .attr('height', imageHeight + "px");

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d', {preserveDrawingBuffer : true});
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);

    var dataURL;
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    callback(dataURL);

}).bind(this, imageWidth, imageHeight);

image.onerror =
image.onabort = function () {
    console.error("generateIcon : error on image");
}

image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(encodeURIComponent(xmlSource).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function (match, p1) {
            return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
        }));
```

Using xmlSource = `"<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 54.4 54.4"><g><circle cx="27.2" cy="27.2" r="21.2" stroke-width="3" stroke="#606060" style="fill: rgb(189, 189, 189);"/><text dx="26" dy="34" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:18px; fill: #000000; font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-weight: bold">90</text></g></svg>"`

The resulting dataURL is:

- Firefox :

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACMAAAAjCAYAAAAe2bNZAAAAHElEQVRYhe3BgQAAAADDoPlTH+ECVQEAAAAAxwATRwABzzGAqwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

- Chrome :

data:image/png;base64,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

Any idea ?

Thanks,
mpe

Comment: Did you try to set canvas width & height using `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` instead of setting them as attributes ?

Comment: Yes I tried it but without success :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set absolute `width` and `height` attributes to your root svg node (e.g in `px`).
The default is `100%` but FF has no way to know relative to what (specs don't say yet).  `
Chrome makes it relative to something that only they know.

So FF won't draw your svg image, on the canvas, but won't fire an error either, since the image has loaded correctly (in an html document, they could know what the dimensions should be relative to).

```js
var xmlSource = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="45" height="45" viewBox="0 0 54.4 54.4"><g><circle cx="27.2" cy="27.2" r="21.2" stroke-width="3" stroke="#606060" style="fill: rgb(189, 189, 189);"/><text dx="26" dy="34" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size:18px; fill: #000000; font-family: Arial, Verdana; font-weight: bold">90</text></g></svg>';
function callback(dataURI){
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = dataURI;
  document.body.appendChild(img);
  console.log(dataURI);
  }
var imageWidth = imageHeight = 45;
var image = new Image();

image.onload = (function (imageWidth, imageHeight) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = imageWidth;
    canvas.height = imageHeight;
    
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d', {preserveDrawingBuffer : true});
    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);

    var dataURL;
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    callback(dataURL);

}).bind(this, imageWidth, imageHeight);

image.onerror =
image.onabort = function () {
    console.error("generateIcon : error on image");
}

image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(encodeURIComponent(xmlSource).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function (match, p1) {
            return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
        }));
```