# Javascript canvas.toDataUrl() not encoding properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, png, image-conversion

I'm trying to take an SVG and convert it to an `image/png` data url.

In Chrome 68 it works perfectly, but in Firefox 61 it renders an empty image with the URL of:

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAUAAAAFACAYAAADNkKWqAAABpElEQVR4nO3BAQ0AAADCoPdPbQ8HFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMCnAUGaAAH3lkeeAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC

My code to convert and SVG is found below. You may recognize, it's pretty much just copy/paste from different sites/questions where others were trying to accomplish this.

```
function importSVG(sourceSVG, height = null, width = null) {

return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    try {
        // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLSerializer
        const svgString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(sourceSVG);
        let svgSize = sourceSVG.getBoundingClientRect();

        let canvas = document.getElementById('compass-canvas');
        canvas.width = width ? width : svgSize.width;
        canvas.height = height ? height : svgSize.height;

        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        let img = document.createElement('img');
        let svg = new Blob([svgString], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
        let DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
        let url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

        img.onload = (function () {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            let png = canvas.toDataURL();
            DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(png);

            resolve({image: png});
        });

        img.onerror =
            img.onabort = function (e) {
                console.error('generateIcon : error on image', e);
            };

        img.src = url;
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log('reject', e);
        reject(e);
    }

});
}
```

Is this an issue that others have encountered in the newer Firefox, or am I missing something that should be pretty obvious?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @HelderSepu said, there is nothing wrong with my code. The issue with firefox is I did not have a height/width set on my SVG element.

I found the solution in @Kaiido's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42529397/1653716)

So, I set the `height` and `width` attribute before using the `XMLSerializer`:

```
sourceSVG.setAttribute('width', 500);
sourceSVG.setAttribute('height', 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me (I did simplify your code to better fit in a snippet):

```js
var svgString = '<svg id="test" width="200px" height="30px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">  <g xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">    <rect fill="#67b7dc" transform="translate(-0.5,-0.5)" width="300" height="50" />    <text fill="#fff"  font-size="25" dy="20"> <tspan> Some text</tspan> </text>  </g></svg>'


let canvas = document.getElementById('compass-canvas');
canvas.width = 200
canvas.height = 50

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let img = document.createElement('img');
let svg = new Blob([svgString], {
  type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
});
let DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
let url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = (function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);  
});

img.src = url;
```

```html
<canvas id='compass-canvas'></canvas>
```

The only difference with your code is that I did hard coded an SVG image to test...
Double check what you have in that sourceSVG to make sure is a valid SVG